# How can I ensure one line of JQuery run before another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user click on a button, I want to show something, then do the ajax request, then hide the thing. But I can't manage to make it happen. My codes:

```
  $('div').on('click', '.button', function(e){    

    $('.spinner').show();   

    $.ajax({
      url: '/url.php', 
      // some other params
    });

    $('.spinner').hide();   
  });
```

I can't make it work. The div just don't show but the ajax went through. Sometimes the ajax would take a few secods so it's not that it shows and hides immediately. Why is it that? How can I force the appearance of the div before running the ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With asynchronous code you can't think "linearly" anymore. Asynchronous operations doesn't "wait" for completion, the just kick off and then the next operation is executed. Instead of your current approach you will have to use callbacks or promises.

For example like this in your case, `$.ajax` method returns an object with the method `done` (or you could use `success` configuration method) which will be invoked once response from the server is available come:

```
$('div').on('click', '.button', function (e) {

    $('.spinner').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/url.php',
        // some other params
    })
    .done(function() {
        $('.spinner').hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something generic:

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('.spinner').show();
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('.spinner').hide();
        });
```

Just add this code, somewhere in your `layout` or `Master Page`, and it will load this spinner, whenever you make any `ajax request`.